# Display multiple tables in same place

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to display 3 tables at the same time in Pg Admin with the following

```
SELECT * FROM movies;

SELECT * FROM movie_cast;

SELECT * FROM person;
```

Only the person (or last table) is displayed. If I run the queries separately the tables are displayed correctly with all the data.

Comment: pgAdmin is not smart enough to deal with more than one result set. Use a different client like `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the results of all three queries at the same time, you can use a UNION clause to combine the results into a single result set.

```sql
SELECT * FROM movies
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM movie_cast
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM person;
```

Make sure to use UNION ALL instead of just UNION if you want to include duplicate rows. If you're certain that there are no duplicates or if you want to remove duplicates, you can use just UNION.